# Retrieve all the ids for a given sentence using regex in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am working on a .Net(C#) software which get and processes an html file. I need to get the id's of the html elements from that file and i want to use regular expression for that. I've tried some combinations but with no luck.
For example, if I have the line:

```
<a href="#" id="thisAnchor" >Link to somewhere</a><div id="divToCollect">BigDiv</div>
```

I want to get: `thisAnchor` and `divToCollect`. I am using Regex:

```
Regex.Matches(currentLine, expression);
```

Comment: Use HtmlAgilityPack for that http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Parsing HTML using Regex is extremely difficult because of the various edge cases. It's better to use an HTML parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the document and search for the items you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use regex for that, use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) and you will have no problems getting all the attributes you need:

```
string html = "<div id='divid'></div><a id='ancorid'></a>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var divIds = doc.DocumentNode
                .Descendants("div")
                .Where(div => div.Attributes["id"] != null)
                .Select(div => div.Attributes["id"].Value)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi DZL, Thanks for the answer,  I know all about HtmlAgilityPack but I don't wanna use it. I need something more efficient by performance, something much faster. I found the solution by using regular expression -> id=\"[^\\\"]+\"  .

Comment: If you control the html and you can make sure that the html is valid that is a good solution, if you do not, that regex can fail. Because what happens if there is <div id='singlequotes' /> in html?

Comment: this can be also treated with regex on the same expression...I will see, I need to manipulate the document in many ways, so the agilityPack can help me with time for development. Thanks again.